# tplink wds ethernet query

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, wds

Model: Archer C20
Hardware Version: V1
Firmware Version: 0.9.1.2.1 v0044.0 Build 151120 Rel.35051n

I have a query I cannot seem to find a definitive answer for. I am trying to setup an old tplink C20 v1 router as a range extender so that I can have a CCTV nvr connected via an ethernet connection and then use the WDS bridge to get internet access. I have setup the WDS bridge between the 2 networks and can confirm that I have internet connectivity from the extender network.

However, my laptop which is plugged into the extender router is unable to connect to the internet. Is this correct? Is this a feature that does not exist on the default TPlink firmware?

Comment: Make sure this setup doesn't use WEP only for the WDS bridge. There are better ways of achieving what you are trying to do. WDS modes half the available bandwidth over the wireless link on an already crowded 2.4ghz band. It's also simplex, and not recommended for video!

Comment: Could you elaborate what the _better ways_ are?

Comment: https://openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tp-link_archer_c20_v1 **installing third party firmware, and using it as a wireless bridge.** Follow the flash instructions word for word. If you fail to do this you can brick the router.

Comment: Or ask a knowledgeable friend for help. I think if worded properly you could ask it as a whole new question here, so keep notes of exactly what you did, and where/if you run into trouble.